# Visual Studio in a virtual machine (WP 8.1 emulator?)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I like have a local virtual machine running on my laptop (Hyper-v) as my development environment. Having Visual Studio installed in the virtual machine.

Everything has been working great.

Now I have to develop WP8.1 apps, and ofcourse the WP emulator does not work inside of the VM.
But I was hoping to deploy Wp8.1 apps directly on a Windows Phone connect by USB. 
This would work if Visual Studio was installed directly on the laptop and not in a VM.

Have anyone been able to do this? Or am I the only one having my development environment hosted in a virtual machine and therefor having these problems? :)

Comment: Hope you've already gone through this before? http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that this allows for USB Redirection / RemoteFX (GPEDIT.msc), so I can now use my device in Visual Studio in my virtual machine.